# Swing paintcomponent malfunction

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw lines based on user input. However, When i run it, it makes the jFrame blank.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0, 250, 500, 1);
    g.drawRect(250, 0, 1, 500);
    g.drawLine(250,250, 250 + Integer.parseInt(b.getText()), 250);
    g.drawLine(
            250 + Integer.parseInt(b.getText()), 
            250, 
            250 + Integer.parseInt(b.getText()),
            250+Integer.parseInt(a.getText()));
    g.drawLine(250, 250, 250 + Integer.parseInt(b.getText()),
            250+Integer.parseInt(a.getText()));
}
```

Comment: Please post a valid [mre] if you want the best answer possible without us having to guess

Comment: Also, I have to wonder about those parseInt calls, that you're not throwing a NumberFormatException by having that in the paintComponent, which runs *before* the user has any time to enter anything into a JTextField.

Comment: In fact, if those text fields should hold numbers, perhaps better to use a JSpinner.

Comment: Yes, of course you can draw using user input, ***if*** the input is valid, but your most specific question, why this paints black is not yet answerable.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels got it. How would you call it after?

Comment: You can't. You need to get the input and validate it, and if invalid, use valid default values, but again, ***please*** improve the question. The specifics will all depend on that which  you are not showing us.

Comment: I already answered that

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ok basically the user inputs coordinates and I want the program to draw a line based on the coordinates. How would I do this?

Comment: Again, use JSpinners, set the values from the start to default values.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how do you use jspinners? ive never used them

Comment: They're similar to JTextFields as the user can enter numbers just like a JTextField, but they also have up-down arrows to change the numeric value. There is a tutorial for them.

Comment: *I'm trying to draw lines based on user inpu* - so then you have two basic steps: 1) you need a way for the user to enter the information. 2) you need to store the information so you can paint each line. One way to do this is to store the information in an ArrayList and then iterate through the list to paint each line. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example. In the example the user uses a mouse to draw the shape. You would need to change the UI to have the user enter the information.

Answer (score 1):

To have the user be able to enter a number and draw with it, use a JSpinner (or multiple JSpinners), since the user cannot add non-numeric values into these, and set it at a default value to start. For example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LinePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Stroke MY_STROKE = new BasicStroke(4f);
    private JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(50, 0, 100, 1));
    private JSpinner spinner2 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(50, 0, 100, 1));
    
    public LinePanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 650));
        add(spinner1);
        add(spinner2);
        
        spinner1.addChangeListener(cEvt -> spinnerChanged());
        spinner2.addChangeListener(cEvt -> spinnerChanged());
    }
    
    private void spinnerChanged() {
        repaint();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setStroke(MY_STROKE);
        int x2 = ((Integer)spinner1.getValue() * getWidth()) / 100;
        int y2 = ((Integer)spinner2.getValue() * getHeight()) / 100;
        g2.drawLine(0, 0, x2, y2);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            LinePanel mainPanel = new LinePanel();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

As to your original question: why your current code isn't working? I myself can't answer this without your posting a decent [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (please see my code above as an example), one that demonstrates the problem for us. Are you getting any NumberFormatExceptions with your code?